# SQLAlchemy - Mapping ResultProxy to mapped classes without a session

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'd very much like to avoid state binding to entities when querying through `session`, and take advantage of class mapping without relying on:

```
session.query(SomeClass)
```

I have no need for transactions, eager/deferred loading, change tracking, or any of the other features offered. Essentially I want to manually bind a `ResultProxy` to the mapped class, and have a list of instances that do not have any references to SQLA (such as state).

I tried Query.instances, but it requires a session instance:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
meta = MetaData()
meta.bind = engine
table = Table('table, meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('field1', String(16), nullable=False),
    Column('field2', String(60)),
    Column('field3', String(20), nullable=False)
)

class Table(object)
    pass

meta.create_all(checkfirst=True)
for i in range(10):
    user.insert({'field1': 'field1'+i,'field2': 'field2'+i*2,'field3': 'field3'+i*4})
mapper(Table, table)
query = Query((Table,))
query.instances(engine.text("SELECT * FROM table").execute())
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2507, in _instance_processor
        session_identity_map = context.session.identity_map
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'identity_map'
```

I'm stuck at this point. I've looked through `Query.instances`, and the manual setup to replicate session seems very extensive. It requires `Query`, `QueryContext`, `_MapperEntity` and an elaborate choreography that would make most ballet companies blush.

**tl;dr** Want to use SQLAlchemy's query generation (anything that returns `ResultProxy` instance) and have results mapped to their respective classes while skipping anything to do with `session`, identity_map & Unit of Work.

Answer (score 0):

you could expunge the object, so it does not maintain a session, but it would still have _sa attributes.

Seeing it's been a while since you asked, it'll probably not serve you, but maybe to others